# MySQL query to exclude string combination

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to see an example in MySQL syntax where  string combination like 'Finance-Finance' should be excluded from the column value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `check` constraint in the most recent versions.  So, one method is:

```
check ( col <> concat(substring_index(col, '-', 1), '-', substring_index(col, '-', 1)))
```

If you just want to filter out rows in an existing table, then use:

```
where col <> concat(substring_index(col, '-', 1), '-', substring_index(col, '-', 1))
```

Comment: I see check is used to CREATE and ALTER table. Can I use check with where clause while pull the data from the table and exclude scenario like Finance-Finance. Any suggestion?